# css vertical text : font-size inheritance and border-radius

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="horizontal">
    <div class="biggest">t e s t <div class="circle">1</div></div>
    <div>t e s t <div class="circle">2</div></div>
    <div>t e s t <div class="circle">3</div></div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.horizontal div {
    float: left;
    width: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.biggest {
    font-size: 150%;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

My output: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaffJ/3/

The following are what I don't understand about what I'm getting:

1. I was expecting the first column encapsulated in class `biggest` to have a larger font size than the rest of the columns, yet I'm getting a uniform font size for all 3 columns.
2. I was expecting a nice circle around each number in class `circle` having set `border-radius: 50%`. What I'm actually getting are some weird ovals.
3. (**update**) To have the number in class `circle` to show up in it's centre.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on and how I could possibly achieve my wanted output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `line-height` of `.circle` to 100%. The css should be `.horizontal .biggest { }` and not just `.biggest { }`. You could also set it like this:

```
.biggest {
    font-size: 150% !important;
}
```

**Full CSS**

```
.horizontal div {
    float: left;
    width: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.horizontal .biggest {
    font-size: 150% ;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.circle span {
    text-align: center;
    width: 2em;
    display: block;
}
```

Wrap your numbers within span's like this:

```
<div>t e s t <div class="circle"><span>2</span></div></div>
```

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uwuquh/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm seeing though from the output that the numbers aren't centred within the circle; are there also any solutions to that?

Comment: Yeah, you could wrap the number with spans. See my updated answer and fiddle: http://jsbin.com/uwuquh/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, that's impressive! Could you quickly go over how the centred text in circles works? I'm noticing that if I copy over the css in `.circle span` all over to `.circle` and remove `.circle span` the text no longer centres.

Answer (score 1):

1. The selector `.horizontal div` is more [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than `.biggest`, fix this by changing the selector to `.horizontal .biggest`
2. Text isn't square because you have defined the width (1em) but not the height, add `height: 1em` to `.circle` or `.horizontal div`

[Fixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaffJ/10/)

Comment: +1 for the link to specific. Are there any solutions though to center the text in the circle though? I'm seeing that they're slightly positioned toward the left.

Comment: @dk123 I'll play around but I don't think so, if you remove the border radius, you will see that the number is not in the middle of the `.circle` element. Text-align: center doesn't fix this so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @dk123 I can't get it to work, I'm afraid all I can suggest is lots of absolute positioning and stuff :/

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to:

```
.horizontal .biggest {
}
```

instead of

```
.biggest {
}
```